# Java connecting to cassandra running inside docker

Tags: java, docker, cassandra

I`m new to cassandra, same as docker. My goal is to connect to cassandra running inside docker from java. I'm working on windows machine

I ran cassandra by executing (also tried ver 2.2, 3.10 and without any env.variables)

```
docker run --name cassandra -d -e CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1 cassandra:3.0
```

Currently I have such docker ps output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                         NAMES

f932d3e7e0dc        cassandra:3.0       "/docker-entrypoin..."   5 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp   cassandra
```

And I can "docker exec -it cassandra cqlsh" with such output

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.13 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
```

In java project I have gradle dependency

```
compile group: 'com.datastax.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-driver-core', version: '3.2.0'
```

My test code (also tried without specifying any protocol version, and tries with V5)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                           .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                           .withProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.V4)
                           .build();
  Session session = cluster.connect();
}
```

And I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:232)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1600)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1518)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:330)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:305)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:247)
    at com.iter.cassandratest.Cassandratest.main(Cassandratest.java:17)
```

Any ideas I`m doing wrong?

Edit 1:

I`ve just tried run with -P option, according to [dock I found](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)

Now ps output is:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                         NAMES

9eb54421aac2        cassandra:3.0       "/docker-entrypoin..."   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:32772->7000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32771->7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32770->7199/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->9042/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->9160/tcp   cassandra
```

I changed code to

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                             .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                             .withPort(32769)
                             .withProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.V4)
                             .build();
```

Exception changed to

```
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:32769 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:32769]     
Channel has been closed))
```

Comment: I guess you should specify port forwarding in your docker machine. Try to connect not to localhost but to the docker IP. i.e. 192.168.99.100 if it would work then it means that the issue is in port forwarding.

Comment: Did you mean container address?
"docker inspect cassandra" does not contain container`s adress. How can i find out the "docker IP"?

Comment: i.e "docker machine ip default" if you are using docker machine 
https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/

Comment: docker-machine ip default - 
Host does not exist: "default". 
docker-machine ip -
Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists.

Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Docker version? Later versions of docker don't use docker-machine.

Comment: Remove the CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1. That is the localhost of the container, so you are jailing the api in the container. Docker only map ports of the eht0 container's interface. Without it and with -P should work

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the solution. Btw docker version is 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

Comment: You should post your solution below as an answer rather than update the question

Comment: Done. I`m sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to connect to localhost with the default port, you need to forward it.

```
docker run --name cassandra -d \
    -p 9042:9042 \
    cassandra:3.0
```

Using `-P` will pick random ports for you based on the `EXPOSE` options of the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rober. The answer is

```
docker run --name cassandra -P -d cassandra:3.0
```

And then connect to port shown in docker ps (32769 for me).